# Grails abstract domain class with hasMany issue

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Hope you can help me with the following... when I´ve an abstract domain class like this

```
abstract class Activity implements Serializable {
    Activity parent
    static hasMany = [childrenActivities: Activity]
    static mappedBy = [childrenActivities: 'parent']
}
```

or

```
abstract class Activity implements Serializable {
    static belongsTo = [parent: Activity]
    static hasMany = [childrenActivities: Activity]
}
```

and some concrete domain classes:

```
class RunActivity extends Activity { }
class WalkActivity extends Activity { }
```

I get the following exception with the hasMany:

```
Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : com.activity.Activity. Stacktrace follows:
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface:  : com.activity.Activity
```

What I´m trying to do is: an Activity can belong to a parent... and an activity can have children activities.

I know that removing the abstract from Activity solves the problem but what will allow to instantiate the super class.

I´m using Grails 2.5.0

Any suggestions?

Comment: When (or doing what) do you get the exception?

Comment: Loading the childrenActivities collection.

Comment: The only person who could instantiate the superclass is the programmer. Gorm inheritance is not as powerful as that in java/groovy. I know using an abstract class makes sense, but your best bet is to make it a regular class.

Comment: @emmanuelRosa that's what I thought and did the change to make it work. thanks!